# Java in websphere produces corrupted zip file, if previously zipped content as byte array is written into file

Tags: java, linux, websphere, zip, java-io

my java zip problem apeears only in websphere in linux environment,
but works on my local windows developer computer in tomee all right.

I try to compress a content and send the result as mail and backup the same content in a folder.

My input data is a CSV file content in a byte-array.

I compress the input byte array to a zip result byte array.

I try to save my zipped result data in a folder and send the same content as a mail attachment.

Result: zip-attachment in mail is delivered correctly but the same zip byte array saved as a file is corrupted.

```
public static byte[] zipContent(String filename, byte[] content) throws IOException {

    final CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (final ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        final InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);) {

      crc.reset();
      final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(filename);
      zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
      int length;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
      while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        crc.update(bytes,0,length);
        zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
      }
      final long crcValue = crc.getValue();
      zipEntry.setCrc(crcValue);
      zipEntry.setSize(content.length);
      zipEntry.setComment("CRC_" + Long.toString(crcValue));

      zipOut.closeEntry();
      zipOut.flush();
    } finally {
      baos.flush();
      baos.close();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }
```

I call

```
final byte[] csvContentArray = ... // Get CSV input anyway ...


File csvFile = new File(aCsvPathString);
Files.write(csvfile.toPath(), csvContentArray); // OKAY, saved correctly pre compress in server


//COMPRESS: byte[] --> byte[]
final byte[] zippedContent = zipContent(csvFileName, csvContentArray);


File zipFile = new File(aZipPathString);
Files.write(zipfile.toPath(), zippedContent); // CORRUPTED, saved after compress in server !!!

...
sendMail(emailAdress, zippedContent);  // the same zipped content in mail is delivered correctly and can be opened without warnings !
```

What differs for zip file content as byte[] between saving in file system and sending as mail attachment (MimeBodyPart).

It is very strange for me, because it works fine in Windows/Tomee but not in Linux/Websphere.

My zipped csv file is huge and after compressing, first about 1000 lines are fine. Rest of file is confused.

I tried to code with and without CRC by ZipEntry, but it doesn't matter.

Opening corrupted zip in 7zip gives warnings like:

*Unerwartetes Datenende.* Translated: unexpected data end.

*Es gibt noch Daten hinter den Hauptdaten.* Translated: existing data after main data.

I'm always grateful for opinions and suggestions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your Linux environment running on a z15 mainframe? There's a known issue with compression on that specific OS/hardware combo, addressed in a recent Java fixpack.

Comment: Hi Jarid, no is not. Our jee application  is not running on mainframe. According to my knowledge, the infrastructure here is based on  usual servers (intel xeon or amd) installed in rack.